# node single request ESOCKETTIMEDOUT

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code below always returns ESOCKETTIMEDOUT. I have tested many url's but this one has me stumped. I assume it has something to do with the certificates not matching.

```
var _request = require('request');

process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0';

const _requestGET = {
    url: "https://www.yellowpages.com.au/",
    followRedirect: false,
    maxRedirects: 10,
    method: "GET",
    timeout: 10000,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    requestCert: true
};

_request(_requestGET, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log("GET: " + (error ? "Error: " + error : response.statusCode));                
});
```

Using wget I can see the the certificates don't match:

> ERROR: cannot verify www.yellowpages.com.au's certificate, issued by /C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA':
>
> Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
> ERROR: certificate common name '*.whitepages.com.au' doesn't match requested host name `www.yellowpages.com.au'.

Comment: Are you using some sort of proxy?

Comment: I have just tried this on a completely different Network on a different machine (MAC) with exactly the same result. Also same happens with .Net client. Wiresharking a browser request and comparing with the request made from here I don't see much difference except this transaction stops after receiving New Session Ticket from Server and nothing is returned from Client.